# CSS Lang selector - dynamic multi language

Tags: html, css, lang

Lets say I know I currently have "en-us". I know I will add more (en-gb and etc.).

I currently use `:lang(en-us)` in CSS. Is there a way to have a CSS variable where I can just add languages, i.e.

`var en = "en-US", "en-gb", "en-whatever"`

and then :lang(us) would represent them all?

Another example would be "es-es", and then I add Mexican Spanish pages so add "es-mx" and want them both handled by the same :lang() tag.

Comment: What would you use these for? I mean as opposed to using the HTML lang attribute.

Comment: Thanks mate - I think I answered my own question - the HTML Lang tag and it's relation to the CSS lang psuedo selector. Essentially - it auto cascades - so (es) also covers (es-es) and (es-mx). Per the docs - and it seems to be panning out on testing.